# distance between two iPhones without using GPS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is there any way to find the distance between two iPhones without using GPS in iOS??
i am working on finding out the exact distance between two iPhones which are few feet away.
Any suggestion, tutorial/links would be appreciated.
Looking forward for reply...

Comment: Hey @daemon22 did you get any solution to get distance.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create some sort of sonar type thing. Use bluetooth between the devices to "arrange" a date stamp and emit a sound from one of the devices at the exact time stamp.

On the second device listen for the sound and mark the timestamp that it comes in at.

Then you can work out how long it took to get from one to the other.

I don't know how accurate that would be though.

Or possibly easier would be to emit a sound from one device then when the second device picks it up it re-emits another sound.

Then the first device listens out for the reply and can find the distance between them in time.

Comment: As i am a novice, It would be great if u could provide any code or any link related to it which could be useful to me. thnx in advance...

Comment: I haven't done anything like this before but I'd do a google search for "ios generate audio frequency" and "ios detect frequency". Have the app have two "modes" listen mode and generate mode. The generate mode is the one that does the first sound the listen mode makes the reply. Then you've got to just time how long the reply takes to come back. If they are 1m apart it will take about 0.006 seconds to bounce back.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is some sort of audio chirp that you could measure the latency between, but at a few feet apart, I don't know that you'd be able to get the two iPhones synchronized closely enough to be able to take an accurate measurement.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there isn't too much noise, you could pair the devices using bluetooth and use the signal intensity as a measure of distance. This will probably require a  lot of trial and error, but I think that without gps it might be your best choice.
You could also go for wifi triangulation if you had enough access points with known locations, but this might be even more inaccurate.

Comment: As i am a novice, It would be great if u could provide any code or any link related to it which could be useful to me.
thnx in advance...